# curl login -> will not login

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to view states from a page that requires login (i have premium membership)

but when running the script it does not retrieve the logged in information - is my login curl script missing something?

```
$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://reg.racingpost.com/mpp/sign_in.sd');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('signinEmail'=>'...@....com', 'signinPassword1'=>'.....'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.racingpost.com/horses/result_home.sd?race_id=650156&r_date=2016-05-29');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');

echo curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: What did you get after curl return?

Comment: I get the page but with the login info hidden

Comment: You login is successful ?

Comment: no as it would have shown the data because i would be logged in

Comment: The password was encrypted or just raw data? For the sake of security   usually client side will encrypted password before sent it to server side. I don't know if this is the reason you failed on login , but you need check it on that site's client.

Comment: raw data - wouldn't be able to check that although i do know scripts have one it before

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with the keys of the variables:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('signinEmail'=>'...@....com', 'signinPassword1'=>'.....'));
```

Should be:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('signInEmail'=>'...@....com', 'signInPassword1'=>'.....'));
                                                  ^ here                        ^ and here
```

Comment: thanks for your reply jeroen ... i cant seem to see the difference in the two lines of code??

Comment: @emmaperkins That's why I marked the changes below the corrected version :-)

Comment: ah yes a capital I!! -> sadly though i gave this ago and still not pulling signed in information :(

Comment: @emmaperkins Have you done a dump of the `cookie.txt` file and does it contain the same kind of information as the cookie contains when you login through your browser?

Comment: @emmaperkins Something like `var_dump(file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt'));`. Then compare it with similar information in the cookie information in the development tools of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help.

```
$post_user_values = array(
    'username' => USERNAME,
    'password' => PASSWORD
); 


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_user_values);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `http://www.racingpost.com/horses/result_home.sd?race_id=650156&r_date=2016-05-29` requires login then don't close the curl and make another curl request with the same `Curl init`. Se below code

```
$curl=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://edeveloper.mppglobal.com/interface/Mpp/eDeveloper/v8/eDeveloper.json.svc/UserAuthenticateByEmail');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array('EmailAddress'=>'...@....com', 'UserPassword'=>'.....')));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');
curl_exec($curl);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.racingpost.com/horses/result_home.sd?race_id=650156&r_date=2016-05-29');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'/cookie.txt');

echo curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Hi - thanks the logic makes sense as i would need to keep that session active! - but i tried the above and still does not show the sign in content

Comment: what your 1st curl_exec($curl); returns?

Comment: if i sign in on it normally it just activates to login sessions

Comment: open your browser console and see

Comment: i used you edited code and its still not signing in :(